# Rounding to the nearest hundredth for currencies in javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, decimal, rounding, calculator

I am creating a tip calculator and I need to find an algorithm in Javascript to round numbers (Tip per person, Tip amount, total amount) to the nearest hundredth to create an acceptable currency solution. Any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Convert to cents, do math, convert back to dollars.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Math.round(num * 100) / 100` or `num.toFixed(2)`

Or, for money specifically, you could do

```
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'USD',
        minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});
formatter.format(num);
```

```js
var num = 123.4567;

console.log(Math.round(num * 100) / 100)

console.log(num.toFixed(2));

var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'USD',
        minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});
console.log(formatter.format(num));
```